# Linux Training courses

Tags: kernel, openstack, development, administration

I am a fresh computer science graduate and I have been a Linux user for five years. I would say that my Linux skills are intermediate, Like I am very comfortable using the Command Line and carrying out administration tasks.

I want to advance my Linux skills and I want to take a course from the Linux foundation. I am choosing between Linux Kernel Internals and Development vs OpenStack administration.

What do you guys think is more beneficial for myself career wise and also building my online portfolio.

I don't know anything about Openstack and I also want to learn about the Linux kernel and be a part of a community and contribute to the open source project.

But I heard people telling me that If i want a job then it's better to learn OpenStack. What do you guys think ?

Comment: Very broad question.  There are literally  millions  of courses online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend both. Two totally different items but it will both benefit you in the long run. If you have an intermediate experience on Linux already. Openstack skills is a complement/supplement to it which provides an opportunity to experience a new platform directly related to cloud implementation. two cents.